# Error: client not configured; see 'gclient config' while building chrome-devtools-frontend

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, gclient

I am building chrome-devtools-frontend on Ubuntu 22.04 via WSL Windows 10 by `gclient sync` I get this error-

```
WARNING: Your metrics.cfg file was invalid or nonexistent. A new one will be created.
Error: client not configured; see 'gclient config'
```

As mentioned in the "[set up](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/main/docs/get_the_code.md#Standalone-checkout-Checking-out-source)" in the [readme](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend?tab=readme-ov-file), i am supposed to run

```
gclient sync
gn gen out/Default
autoninja -C out/Default
```

to build devtools for standalone.

I have both gn & autoninja & gclient installed. I am very new to this & know literally nothing about any of these tools, please be kind to help me build chrome devtools frontend.

Thank you in advance